# Folders statics not found in server google - Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, static, webdeploy, filenotfounderror

Django cannot find the static files on the google server, the
`python manage.py collectstatic`
command has already been used with the settings.py configured.

[image]
[image]

To solve this problem I followed several tutorials that showed us how to deploy static files, including the documentation itself. However, none got results. It is worth mentioning that this same code and configuration worked in the homolog version of the system.

Comment: Did you setup this folder as a static directory in the `handlers` section of your `app.yaml`? I think when you do that, gcloud actually uploads it differently, because it gets served directly out of a GCS bucket or something, instead from your instance.

Comment: Hello, I followed your recommendations about the app.yaml file and the error still persisted. But checking the server configuration internally, we realized that it was all configured for projects in another language and old versions. So the current project won't actually run on that machine.